# Runtime 1004 on Userform_intialize when reffering to range in different Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm having a hard time to get my Userform to initialize properly. I have located the problem but can't seem to find the solution.

I want to populate three listboxes when the Userform is started. The RowSource has to be dynamic.

Here is the code shortened to the relevant parts.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim varUserVE As Variant
Dim varUserBL As Variant
Dim varUserFL As Variant

'Find RowSource in Sheet Settings
With Settings
    varUserVE = .Range("B7", Range("F80").End(xlUp)).Address
    varUserBL = .Range("H7", Range("L80").End(xlUp)).Address
    varUserFL = .Range("N7", Range("R80").End(xlUp)).Address
End With

'Fill lists
With lstVE
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100;50;85;50"
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .RowSource = varUserVE
End With

With lstBL
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100;50;85;50"
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .RowSource = varUserBL
End With

With lstFL
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100;50;85;50"
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .RowSource = varUserFL
End With

End Sub
```

"Settings" is the codename for the sheet.

The Code works just fine when the sheet "Settings" is selected. If I select a different sheet and run the code however:
Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed

Ive tried several ways of refering to that sheet which all failed. I am relatively new to vba so I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic when refering to ranges.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This section might be causing you problem.

```
With Settings
    varUserVE = .Range("B7", Range("F80").End(xlUp)).Address
    varUserBL = .Range("H7", Range("L80").End(xlUp)).Address
    varUserFL = .Range("N7", Range("R80").End(xlUp)).Address
End With
```

You used .Range on the first part, but it's missing "." in the Range("F80").....

So it will be same thing as

```
varUserVE = .Range("B7", Activesheet.Range("F80").End(xlup)).Address
```

Try adding "."

```
With Settings
    varUserVE = .Range("B7", .Range("F80").End(xlUp)).Address
    varUserBL = .Range("H7", .Range("L80").End(xlUp)).Address
    varUserFL = .Range("N7", .Range("R80").End(xlUp)).Address
End With
```

Comment: Wow. I have been looking at this strip of code for hours and didn't see it. Seeing the wood for the trees and all that. Thanks alot, good sir!!